# 'this' and 'prototype', simple function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to resolve a problem but I need to understand prototype.

I was reading and I thought I got it, but I am still having some complications

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + name;
}

var kate = new Person('Kate'); //name
var jose = new Person('Jose'); //otherName ???
```

so, is my mistake when I need to call the function ? or where is it ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You create two instances of person, but that is all.  You never call `greet()` on any of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` is a property of the object instance, so you need to use `this.name` in the `greet` method.

From what I understand, you need to display `Hi Jose, my name is Kate` like a greeting. In that case you need to pass the `other person` to the `greet` method then you can access that persons name using `object.name`

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(other) {
  return "Hi " + other.name + ", my name is " + this.name;
}

var kate = new Person('Kate');
var jose = new Person('Jose');

snippet.log(kate.greet(jose));
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```